# rails 3 and refreshed cached object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, dalli

I'm new to caching, but I've got memcached working with rails and I'm using the Dalli gem.

In the rails console, i'm able to cache an object and then read it back out no problem

```
    Rails.cache.write("unique_posts",Post.new.get_uniques)
    posts=Rails.cache.fetch('unique_posts')
```

How do i set the refresh rate/expiring to the Rails.cache.write command?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to pass the `:expires_in` option. So, basically this will work

```
Rails.cache.write("unique_posts",Post.new.get_uniques, expires_in: 10.minutes)
posts=Rails.cache.fetch('unique_posts')
```

Pro tip, do this.

```
posts = Rails.cache.fetch('unique_post' , expires_in: 10.minutes) { Post.new.get_uniques }
```